# Refresh Fragment inside tabhost. OnSetUserVisibleHint is not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, refresh, android-tabhost

I want to do a refresh on my fragment that is inside a tabhost when it is visible.
The setup was there is a ViewPager, on page X, there's a fragment with a tabhost and 2 child fragments in it. I want to refresh do something if first child of the tabhost is visible.

Please help me.

setUserVisibleHint is not called on my fragment(child) but called on the fragment parent.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you using `TabHost` or `FragmentTabHost`?

Comment: i am using a Fragment Tabhost.